# I need couple of queries with DATEDIFF

Tags: sql, ms-access, datediff

1.) List the revenue for each hotel received so far i.e. for DepartureDate  <  NOW(). The calculation must be done in the SQL statement.  Determine the length of each reservation (i.e. number of days) using the DateDiff function and multiply this value by the room rate (not the discounted rate).  Include the hotel number in the output.

So far I have tried this but it's not right and giving me aggregate function error for DateDiff statement

```
SELECT ROOM.HotelNo, DateDiff("d", [ArrivalDate], [DepartureDate]) *  ROOM_TYPE.RoomRate AS TotalRevenue
FROM RESERVATION, ROOM_TYPE, ROOM
WHERE ROOM.RoomType = ROOM_TYPE.RoomType
AND RESERVATION.RoomNo = ROOM.RoomNo
AND DepartureDate > Now()
GROUP BY ROOM.HotelNo;
```

Here is the link where you can see the Table

[RelationShip Table](http://www.mediafire.com/download/7m4ciuxgbb4v8m8/Report1.pdf) **<-- LINK**

Please help me to solve this problem

Comment: What is the actual error? Have you tried `DATEDIFF([DepartureDate],[ArrivalDate])` seems mysql `DATEDIFF` takes 2 arguments and returns days. Also your current order will return a negative value. Also why not use JOIN Statements in your query?

Comment: I'm joining three tables right after where statement

Comment: Actual error is " Your query does not include the specified expression 'DateDiff("d", [ArrivalDate], [DepartureDate])*ROOM_TYPE.RoomRate' as part of an aggregate function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Sum()` of the `DateDiff()` expression to avoid the *"does not include the specified expression ... as part of an aggregate function"* complaint.

```sql
SELECT
    ROOM.HotelNo,
    Sum(
        DateDiff(
                "d",
                [ArrivalDate],
                [DepartureDate]
            ) * ROOM_TYPE.RoomRate
        ) AS TotalRevenue
```

The `WHERE` clause includes `DepartureDate > Now()`, which I suspect filters the results to those which have not yet departed.  I think you want `<` instead of `>` there.

Consider using `INNER JOIN` instead of using the `WHERE` clause to specify how rows from the tables are matched.  If you can build this query from Design View of the Access query designer, setting up the joins will be easy.  And the query designer knows the rule about required parentheses when joining more than 2 tables ... so will produce SQL which keeps the db engine happy.

Comment: Well I can't not use Query from Design view. I'm only allowed to use the SQL mode and write the whole code.  that being said the code that you added(SUM) in SELECT statement with that and change of > To < sign. it works code came with total revenue for each hotel.  I really Appreciate your help. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

As [engineersmnky](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19937467/i-need-couple-of-queries-wiht-datediff/19938125#comment29670806_19937467) points out, your [DATEDIFF](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff) is wrong. It should be 2 parameters, and departure then arrival date:

```
SELECT 
    ROOM.HotelNo, 
    DATEDIFF(RESERVATION.DepartureDate, RESERVATION.ArrivalDate) *  ROOM_TYPE.RoomRate AS TotalRevenue
FROM RESERVATION
JOIN ROOM ON 
    RESERVATION.RoomNo = ROOM.RoomNo
JOIN ROOM_TYPE ON
    ROOM.RoomType = ROOM_TYPE.RoomType
WHERE RESERVATION.DepartureDate > NOW()
GROUP BY ROOM.HotelNo;
```

I am not sure why you have brackets around the DepartureDate and ArrivalDate as they are just columns on the RESERVATION table correct?

Comment: Yes they are columns in Reservation Table.  I just looked online how to use DateDiff Funtion and that's how it was showing that's why i used.

Comment: It looks like [**MSSQL** has a third parameter](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx) so that may be where you got that from, my answer above is for MySQL - is that what you are using?

Comment: No I'm Using MS Access

Comment: Oh. Ha! I'm sorry, this question was tagged MySQL. I am afraid I don't know Access at all.

Comment: I have removed the MySQL tag from this question and added an MS-Access tag. Best of luck, but I am afraid I can't help any further.